# After executing "systeminfo" commaind, waitforsingleobject stopped

Tags: c++, createprocess, waitforsingleobject

So if you run the code below it will stop at `int retVal = WaitForSingleObject( processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);` forever. But when I run "ipconfig" or "ping 192.168.0.1" instead of "systeminfo", the code works perfectly. I would like to know how to solve the problem and what is the reason cause this problem?

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(
                   HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpComLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr; 
    HANDLE hRead,hWrite;

secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 
secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
if (!CreatePipe(&hRead,&hWrite,&secAttr,0)) 
{ 
    return FALSE; 
} 

char command[1024];
strcpy(command, "systeminfo");

STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo; 
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
GetStartupInfo(&startupInfo); 
startupInfo.hStdError = hWrite;  
startupInfo.hStdOutput = hWrite;    
startupInfo.hStdInput = hRead;      
startupInfo.lpTitle = "CMD";
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; 
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, command,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInfo)) 
{ 
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error", NULL, MB_OK);
    CloseHandle(hWrite); 
    CloseHandle(hRead); 
    return FALSE; 
} 

char buffer[1024] = {0};         
DWORD bytesRead; 

int retVal = WaitForSingleObject( processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
if (retVal == WAIT_FAILED)
    MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_FAILED", NULL, MB_OK);
else if (retVal == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    MessageBox(NULL, "WAIT_TIMEOUT", NULL, MB_OK);
ReadFile(hRead,buffer,1024,&bytesRead,NULL);
MessageBox(NULL, buffer, NULL, MB_OK);

CloseHandle(hWrite); 
CloseHandle(hRead);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't have any trouble running your code, I suspect I know the issue.

You are likely deadlocking between the process trying to write to your pipe handle and your code waiting for it to exit.

`systeminfo` writes out at least 2K worth of data to the pipe.  That might exceed the buffer built into the pipe.  But your program isn't simultaneously reading from it.  So the systeminfo program can't exit because it's stuck writing to stdout.  And your program blocks waiting for the application to exit.  Classic deadlock.  Programs that don't output as many characters work fine.

I don't have time to code a complete solution, but I believe you'll want to use a loop that does a WaitForMultipleObjects for both the read handle and the process handle.  Use non-blocking or overlapped i/o on the Read handle if possible.

Also, modify your ReadFile call as follows:

```
DWORD dwResult = ReadFile(hRead,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1,&bytesRead,NULL);
if (dwResult > 0)
{
   buffer[dwResult] = '\0';
}
```

Such that you guaranteed null termination when the entire buffer is filled up with characters.

Comment: OK, what you said make sense to me, and I kinda understand what is the problem in my program. But how does the same code works when you ran it while it doesnt work on my compiler? And I still can't figure out the solusion. I want to ReadFile after systeminfo program exit completely.

Comment: You are totally right, pipe write buff is 4kb on my computer. Somehow i think it is 64kb on yours thats why it runs perfectly on your computer. I used file redirect output instead of pipe. I can get the output successfully now, but I still make input to console any solution?